# Android SDK/ Eclipse IDE/ Java SDK Set-Up?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, windows-7

I am running Windows 7 32-bit Starter OS and I wonder if anyone would be willing to help walk me through the set up for the Java SDK, Eclipse "Indigo" IDE and Android SDK/ADT set-up as I have basically made a bloody mess of it.

I am working out of a couple of books whose instructions are more or less: "go to the download page and follow the instructions" and of course I have, but I keep hitting a brick wall and I am going to delete, re-download, and re-install the entire set-up starting from scratch in the morning.

I was using App Inventor, and had no appreciation of how much work was being done for me behind the scenes until I jumped off into this and will probably try to go back to it if and when Google completes the hand-off of the software to MIT and makes the sourcecode public like they are saying next year. Hmmmm.......

If I can work this out, I will make a click-by-click tutorial out of it and post it for others -who are bound to be having the same issues- to use... it's a rough thing to try to work out something starting from jump street and not knowing where to go when its holding up your entire operation.

I come looking for help -but will help back in return and have lots of stuff I can help with... GUI design is one area I see a lot of folks needing help with- simple little things sometimes make an unbelievable difference, etc.

Anyway if someone will help, point to help, or mention anything that will help, I will be glad.

I also have a list of compiler/console errors and warnings that I am getting when I try to import/run the example code from the books I am working out of -if that will tell anyone anything-. Also glad to receive e-mails about this from anyone.

Kind Regards, mark-p.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html is one of the best step by step on-line instructions on how setup your development environment

Comment: Hey Buddie-- thank you so much-- i will go there now && Happy Holidays... Kind Regards, mark-p.

Comment: Hey-- i found an excellent, excellent video tutorial at YouTube by accident-- here : http://youtu.be/OIL1UouA4dE && again-- thanks to all. Kind Regards, mark-p.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully installed Android SDK in my Windows 7 machine last week and that too with all the latest updates.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html is itself a good resource. These instructions are applicable to the latest JDK version 7, Eclipse Indigo, and SDK Version 15.

The basic steps would be:

1. Download Install JDK 7 from Java site.
2. Download Eclipse Indigo as you would have done already.
3. Install the Android SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. Use the latest installer available ( Currently installer_r15-windows.exe). Note that this installation will install the sdk into Program Files\Android by default.
4. Run Eclipse. Go to Window -> Preferences. You will see a Android tab on the left if your SDK was installed properly.Ensure that your SDK location is same as your actual installation path.

5.Install the ADT Plugin for Eclipse.Go to Help->Install New software. Check http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing for detailed instructions.

1. Now go to Window-> Android SDK Manager.This should launch a window and the SDK Manager will try to retrieve the list of installed/available packages from the Google repository. Make sure that your internet connection is correct. **If your are using a proxy server, go to Tools of SDK Manager and give the IP and port of the proxy server.** I believe I wasted a lot of time since I missed the proxy settings. Also you may need to force https:// to http request.

The above step should list out a set of packages including Android 4.0(API 14) which is the latest platform available today. Select the different packages and on installation and restart of Eclipse, you should be ready to start with your Hello Android program.

Comment: Hey-- in the last 24 hours i have found some fairly good looking stuff on YouTube as well that i am going to be looking at for a coupl'a days at least.